# Admin API For Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have been trying to analyse GA data from my java server. On our react application we are calling

```
GA.setUserId(<some_unique_id>); //GA
```

We have found that this is being properly recorded in GA using the GA admin panel. However what I would like to is periodically query this data from our Java server to analyze the data. We have not been able to find a GA Admin API which allows us to query the data related to the user with id <some_unique_id>.

I understand this was a feature that was supported in previous version of GA and that the feature is not yet available in the new version of GA.

I am hoping that I am simply wrong and would love it if someone would tell me that. Please, please tell me I am wrong!

Thanks!

Comment: Admin api is still in alpha you may need to wait for new features to be released